How to get back CSS Variable value from Radix UI Colors via Javascript/Typescript?
Quite simply I'm trying to dynamically get back the Radix Colors values in JavaScript, reasons for this requirement and why I am unable to hardcode the values is because I also generate these colors from any color the user might pick from an input and this results in the values to be well... different based on what the user picks.
That said I need a way to access the values inside a CSS variable, the variables stay the same, just the value changes.
Currently in my component I tried to use this method to get back the values but it returns me an empty string always, I've put my logs into a setTimeout to rule out the possibility of the variable not being declared first somehow.
const [accent7Color, setAccent7Color] = useState('');
  const [accent8Color, setAccent8Color] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {

    // Tried with document.documentElement also
    const rootStyles = getComputedStyle(document.body);

    const accent7 = rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--accent-7').trim();
    const accent8 = rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--accent-8').trim();

    setAccent7Color(accent7);
    setAccent8Color(accent8);
    setTimeout(() => {

      console.log('Accent 7 Color:', accent7);
      console.log('Accent 8 Color:', accent8);
      console.log(accent7Color);
      console.log(accent8Color);

    }, 4000);
  }, []);

A disclaimer maybe is that this code does not live at the root of the application, maybe that's the problem? Its nested deep in the app.
I've also tried to define the "rootStyles" outside of the useEffect and put that into the dependency array so that I definitely only run this when this rootStyles gets defined or changes value, didn't change a thing. I'm damb damb I need assistance.
So yeah, above mentions were tried and this wasn't really working and I do not see anything else said online about this.

The component runs after the CSS variables have been applied or updated in the DOM.
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';

const ColorComponent = () => {
  const [accent7Color, setAccent7Color] = useState('');
  const [accent8Color, setAccent8Color] = useState('');

  useEffect(() => {
 setTimeout(() => {
      
      const rootStyles = getComputedStyle(document.documentElement);

      const accent7 = rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--accent-7').trim();
      const accent8 = rootStyles.getPropertyValue('--accent-8').trim();

      setAccent7Color(accent7);
      setAccent8Color(accent8);

      console.log('Accent 7 Color:', accent7);
      console.log('Accent 8 Color:', accent8);
    }, 100);
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>Accent 7 Color: {accent7Color}</p>
      <p>Accent 8 Color: {accent8Color}</p>
    </div>
  );
};


Unfortunately this isn't really doing the job, I get back a log for an empty string, I've gone ahead and set the timeout to a higher value just to be sure and even if I wait like 10 seconds it just returns me an empty string, I suspect that its because of the UI Library I use, its Radix.
